# ¿Cómo puedo mezclar dos cadenas de caracteres de forma intercalada usando StringBuilder?

Tags: programación-bajo-nivel

Escribir un programa en Java que:

1. lea dos cadenas de caracteres por teclado de longitud al menos cinco caracteres cada una;
2. genere una nueva cadena cuyo resultado va a ser la mezcla de los caracteres de las dos cadenas anteriores intercalando carácter a carácter;
3. muestre por pantalla esa nueva cadena resultante.

La cadena final debe construirse con StringBuilder.

A continuación se muestra un ejemplo de ejecución del programa:

[image: No se debe usar la concatenación en ningún momento]

*dado que hay que usar un StringBuilder para almacenar el resultado final, no hay que usar la concatenación en ningún momento (no se podrá usar + o el método concat para concatenar).

Comment: Es necesario mostrar lo que se ha intentado para recibir ayuda. No podemos hacer el trabajo por ti; sólo te ayudamos a entender, a corregir fallos y similares.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no hay código alguno, tan solo el enunciado de una tarea de clase.

Answer (score 1):

Esto se puede mejorar pero solo quiero guiarte para que entiendas como pensar el ejercicio

## Obtencion de las cadenas

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es obtener mediante teclado una cadena de minimo 5 caracteres. Para esto puedes utilizar un bucle do { .. }while(condicion);

```
do{
  System.out.print("Introduce una cadena de 5 o más caracteres: ");
  cadena1 = teclado.nextLine();
  if (cadena1.length()<5){
      System.out.println("Cadena no válida.");
      }
  }while (cadena1.length()<5);
```

Una vez realices esto 2 veces tendras las cadenas de al menos 5 caracteres que te solicita el ejercicio.

### Antes que continues te recomiendo pensar en como lidiar con los espacios que pueda introducir un usuario

(Pista: Mira los metodos que puedes usar al manejar un String.)

## Mezcla de las cadenas

En el ejercicio te pide que mezcles 2 cadenas, pero no sabes el tamaño de esas cadenas, solo sabes que como minimo son 5 caracteres, pero no cual sera mas larga que la otra.

Asi que la forma mas facil es cortar las cadenas por la mas corta de las 2 que has recibido por teclado y guardar el resto de la cadena cortada ya que no se mezclara.

```
Por ejemplo:
    cad1    papafrita
    cad2    jamon
```

Aqui la cadena 1 es mayor que la cadena 2 por lo que cortando y guardando el resto quedaria asi:

```
   cad1_cortada: papaf
   cad2          jamon
   cad_resto:    rita
```

Como te piden usar StringBuilder para la construccion de la cadena salida que se mostrara en resultado crea un StringBuilder

```
 StringBuilder cadena3=new StringBuilder();
 String cadenaResto = new String();
```

Ahora pasemos a hacer los cortes y la mezcla de caracteres usando por supuesto StringBuilder.

Comprueba cual de las dos cadenas es mayor y realiza el corte de esa por la longitud de la cadena menor y luego con un bucle for ve mezclando caracter a caracter añadiendo con el metodo append ya que este añade el caracter por detras.

```
    if (cadena1.length()<=cadena2.length()){
        cadena4 = cadena2.substring(cadena1.length());
        for(int i=0; i<cadena1.length();i++){
            cadena3.append(cadena1.substring(i,i+1));
            cadena3.append(cadena2.substring(i,i+1));
        }
    }
    else{    
      ESTO TE LO DEJO A TI PARA QUE NO TE HAGA YO TODO EL EJERCICIO...
        }
     }
```

Se podria haber usado charAt(i) pero en el ejercicio te piden que lo hagas con substring

ya solo te queda añadir el resto de la cadena que guardaste

```
  cadena3.append(cadenaResto);
```

## Mostrar el resultado

```
    System.out.println("RESULTADO: CADENAS MEZCLADAS");
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    System.out.println("El resultado de mezclar \""+cadena1+"\" con \""+cadena2+"\" es \""+cadena3+"\"");
```

Un saludo!

Comment: No es bien visto responder a preguntas que solo exponen tareas sin mayor evidencia de avance y dudas puntuales

Comment: Bueno, yo creo que la respuesta está muy bien planteada, tratando de ayudar al preguntador a aprender sobre lo que ha preguntado. No es solo la respuesta en código. También le invita a reflexionar en varios puntos sobre cómo debería ser el código, etc. A mí me parece bien esta respuesta. Creo que hay que encontrar el equilibro entre no responder a la gente que no sabe preguntar y dar respuesta sin explicaciones. Esta respuesta trata de buscar ese equilibrio.